# How to prove this statement with A,B matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let us have two matrices: $A,B$ which are both $n$ x $n$ type, and $AB+A+B=0$ stands. Prove, that in this case, $AB = BA$.

I tried to do such matrices, and the statement stands, but how should I do a proving in general? Thanks!

Comment: Start by adding $I$ to both sides of your equation.

Comment: True, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

$(A+I)(B+I)=I$ (I'll leave it to you to check). So $(B+I)(A+I)=I$ (both inverses of each other) hence $BA+B+A=0$ and since $AB+A+B=0$ then $BA=AB$

Answer (score 1):

First we have the following because if $XY=I$ then  $YX=I$ hence $0=AB+A+B=(A+I)(B+I)-I$ implies $(B+I)(A+I)=I$and from here you're almost done because $(B+I)(A+I)-I=BA+B+A$

Answer (score 0):

The following must apply simultaneously
$$AB+A+B=0$$
$$BA+B+A=0$$
Subtract the two equations and get the assumption.